# Multiple reader file java

Tags: java, xml, multithreading, synchronization, xml-serialization

I'm currently using Java 6 with Spring 3.

I have some processes that are reading the same file, in this case is XML file.

Also, this processes need to update the content of that file which is I need to update a date.

The process run simultaneously, so there's a possibility they will read and try to write at the same time.

I heard about ReadWriteLock, which can have multiple reader and only 1 writer.
I'm considering that at the moment. But because the process is running quickyly,

There will be a scenario when process A is currently writing an update, and process B is waiting and another process C is waiting for writing the update. Process B might be just an old update if process B is updating the same element.

Is there any idea how can I achieve this?

Thanks,

Comment: Do you have several *processes* accessing the same file or several *threads* accessing the same file? You can use different approaches for threads than for processes.

Comment: Hammer (multithreading) meet nail (single-file writing).

Comment: Unless the file is exceptionally big, there is no reason to even try not to keep in memory. If you are attempting to share a file between more than a single process for concurrent updates/reads, the design is just plain wrong.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

If all of the "processes" are threads, use synchronization.  That is exactly what this is for.  ReadWriteLock won't protect the file itself anyhow; it is for coordinating shared access to objects in memory.

Something like this pseudo-code:

```
class XmlDatabase {

Document doc = readXml();

synchronized Date readDate()  {
    Date _date = getDateFromDoc(doc);
    return _date;
}

synchronized void writeDate(Date _date) {
    addDateToDoc(_date);
    writeDocToFile(doc);
}
```

}

A lot of people will tell you that synchronization is slow, etc.  Unless you're implementing something that is meant to be massively concurrent using synchronization primitives will work fine.  You can always optimize with java.util.concurrent later on if needed.  The simplicity and readability of using plain synchronization is worth it.  If you need to give other processes access to the data, just wrap the database class with RMI or some other networking solution.

Comment: Locks are for coordination in general.  A ReadWriteLock will protect a file no better or worse than it will protect memory.  It just makes sure a reader and a writer don't hold the lock at the same time; *what* they read and write could be anything, and the lock doesn't care.